# Is there a way to filter/avoid duplicate attribute names in keycloak SAML assertions?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, keycloak, nextcloud

I'm trying to setup SSO with nextcloud (13.0.4) and keycloak (4.0.0.Final) (as SSO/SAML IDP und user management solution) like described at [SSO with SAML, Keycloak and Nextcloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48400812/sso-with-saml-keycloak-and-nextcloud).

However, trying to login to nextcloud with the SSO test user configured in keycloak, nextcloud complaints with the following error:

```
OneLogin_Saml2_ValidationError: Found an Attribute element with duplicated Name

/var/www/html/nextcloud/custom_apps/user_saml/3rdparty/vendor/onelogin/php-saml/lib/Saml2/Auth.php - line 177: OneLogin_Saml2_Response->getAttributes()
/var/www/html/nextcloud/custom_apps/user_saml/lib/Controller/SAMLController.php - line 219: OneLogin_Saml2_Auth->processResponse('ONELOGIN_1111a8...')
[internal function] OCA\User_SAML\Controller\SAMLController->assertionConsumerService()
/var/www/html/nextcloud/lib/private/AppFramework/Http/Dispatcher.php - line 161: call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
/var/www/html/nextcloud/lib/private/AppFramework/Http/Dispatcher.php - line 91: OC\AppFramework\Http\Dispatcher->executeController(Object(OCA\User_SAML\Controller\SAMLController), 'assertionConsum...')
/var/www/html/nextcloud/lib/private/AppFramework/App.php - line 115: OC\AppFramework\Http\Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(OCA\User_SAML\Controller\SAMLController), 'assertionConsum...')
/var/www/html/nextcloud/lib/private/AppFramework/Routing/RouteActionHandler.php - line 47: OC\AppFramework\App main('OCA\\User_SAML\\C...', 'assertionConsum...', Object(OC\AppFramework\DependencyInjection\DIContainer), Array)
[internal function] OC\AppFramework\Routing\RouteActionHandler->__invoke(Array)
/var/www/html/nextcloud/lib/private/Route/Router.php - line 297: call_user_func(Object(OC\AppFramework\Routing\RouteActionHandler), Array)
/var/www/html/nextcloud/lib/base.php - line 999: OC\Route\Router->match('/apps/user_saml...')
/var/www/html/nextcloud/index.php - line 42: OC handleRequest()
{main}
enter
```

I wonder if there is a way to avoid/filter duplicate attribute names in keycloak to circumvent the problem?

I've set up a test docker-compose.yml to show the problem (localhost only, without https, i.e. for testing only).

```
# Use only for testing the BASE_PATH feature
# An unencrypted nextcloud will be accessible at
# http://localhost/${BASE_PATH}
version: '3.3'
services:
  app:
    image: aanno/nextcloud:13.0.4-apache
    ports: 
        - 8081:80
    container_name: nextcloud-docker-apache
    volumes:
# Attention: Adapt this to your BASE_PATH
#      - ./apps:/var/www/html/nextcloud/custom_apps
#      - ./config:/var/www/html/nextcloud/config
       - ./data:/var/www/html/nextcloud/data
    environment:
        - BASE_PATH=/nextcloud
    networks:
        - bridge
  keycloak_container:
    image: jboss/keycloak
    container_name: keycloak-server
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
      # defaults to:
      # -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
      # -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true
      #- JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx512m
      - DB_VENDOR=h2
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin1234
    networks:
        - bridge

networks:
    bridge:
        external:
            name: app
```

Keycloak will be at http://localhost:8080 and nextcloud at http://localhost:8081/nextcloud . This file could be found also at https://github.com/aanno/nextcloud-docker/blob/tp/set-base-url-2/13.0/apache/test/docker-compose.yml . At this place you also can details about the docker image (it is based on the official nextcloud/docker image for 13.0-apache).

Comment: In my example I did **not** setup a identitiy Provider (idp). So I don't  what is you configuration in that part. Also, I'd be interested to know **why** you set it up (your keycloak + nextcloud will run just fine without one). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51011422/edit) your and add more details how you setup keycloak and nextcloud and also why you are trying to use a idp.

Comment: Dear MadMike, perhaps my wording was a bit fuzzy first and hence I edited my question a bit. What I actually did is to follow your solution step by step (the only difference I'm aware of is that I use another docker image for nextcloud). However, I always get the mentioned error.

Comment: What did you use instead of `domain.com`? Did you create more than one user? Did you create a user directly on nextcloud? Which docker-image do you use? Speaking of which... please post your docker-compose.yml... remove the passwords, leave the rest.

Comment: I added a docker-compose file to my question to show the problem (on localhost). But I also tried on a real domain (with https by let's encrypt) and run into the very same problem.

Comment: I wouldn't know where to start looking with this kind of error. I've never had one like this. Maybe ask https://help.nextcloud.com/ ?

Comment: Does this apply ? https://help.nextcloud.com/t/solved-nextcloud-saml-keycloak-as-identity-provider-issues/19293/4

Answer (score 6):

Because I also posted this as bug at https://github.com/nextcloud/user_saml/issues/222 , I now know the solution: You have to activate the 'Single Role Attribute' switch.

In keycloak 4.0.0.Final the option is a bit hidden under:
(Realm) -> Client Scopes -> role_list (saml) -> Mappers tab -> role list -> 'Single Role Attribute'.

Answer (score 4):

**There now is a better answer**, posted at https://github.com/nextcloud/user_saml/issues/222#issuecomment-648974404

waza-ari commented 23 days ago

> I know this one is quite old, but its one of the pages you stumble
> across when looking for this problem. There is a better option than
> the proposed one! The proposed option changes the role_list for every
> Client within the Realm. It is better to override the setting on
> client level to make sure it only impacts the Nextcloud client.
>
> For this. edit your client, go to Client Scopes and remove role_list
> from the Assigned Default Client Scopes.
>
> Next, create a new Mapper to actually map the Role List:
>
> ```
> Name: anything you like
> Mapper Type: Role List
> Role Attribute name: Role
> Friendly Name: Anything you like
> SAML Attribute Name Format: Basic
> Single Role Attribute: ON
> ```
>
> Hope this helps someone.